# ClientBase<TChannel> CacheSetting in PCL

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xamarin

We have a Xamarin.iOS project with usage of WCF and we are using generated service client to communicate with server. Problem is, it takes ~500ms to create client for each request.

On WPF project, which uses the same server, service client is inherited from ClientBase which is in System.ServiceModel assembly, which is superior to ClientBase in System.ServiceModel.Primitives assembly that is used on Xamarin. Non-PCL ClientBase implements IDisposable and has CacheSetting property both these features reduce the lag significantly.

Is there any way to implement caching and IDisposable on PCL version of ClientBase?

Comment: What are you using to generate your service client? I've used the Silverlight 5 SDK's svcutil.exe for this, and the client does implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: ClientBase itself doesn't have `IDisposable` declared, although it has the method. As for what I'm using - not sure, it is generated by VS via service configuration.